# Is there an easy way to convert from 32bit integer to 16bit integer?

Tags: c#, int, type-conversion

I have a 32 bit int and I want to address only the lower half of this variable. I know I can convert to bit array and to int16, but is there any more straight forward way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It you want only the lower half, you can just cast it: `(Int16)my32BitInt`

In general, if you're extending/truncating bit patterns like this, then you do need to be careful about signed types - unsigned types may cause fewer surprises.

As mentioned in the comments - if you've enclosed your code in a 'checked' context, or changed your compiler options so that the default is 'checked', then you can't truncate a number like this without an exception being thrown if there are any non-zero bits being discarded - in that situation you'd need to do:

```
(UInt16)(my32BitInt & 0xffff)
```

(The option of using signed types is gone in this case, because you'd have to use `& 0x7fff` which then preserves only 15 bits)

Comment: This will throw an OverflowException if my32BitInt is too large.

Comment: You'd only get an exception in a checked context - which isn't the default behaviour of C#

Comment: Well, what will it do in an unchecked context? The OP wants the lower 16 bits of the number. Does unchecked give you that?

Comment: Neat. However, `checked` is the default (or rather, it depends on compiler options). You should add the `unchecked` context to your example. `unechecked((Int16)my32BitInt)` will do, and it doesn't depend on compiler options :)

Comment: 'checked' is not the default in any version of VS I've ever used

Comment: Yeah, I tried it with LINQPad, which has it as a default. But still, this kind of code should always explicitly invoke an unchecked context, because it explicitly does not care about overflows. The semantics are important here, not the actual execution.

Answer (score 2):

just use this function

```
Convert.ToInt16()
```

or just

```
  (Int16)valueasint
```

Comment: This will throw, rather than trim, if the value is too big or small.

Comment: I think this will give you an overflow exception.

Comment: in either case you will get overflowexception

Comment: @JulieShannon, that would only happen in a `checked` context. In an unchecked context, arithmetic overflow is ignored and the result is truncated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *implicit conversation* to `Int16` like;

```
(Int16)2;
```

**but** be careful when you do that. Because `Int16` can't hold all possible `Int32` values.

For example this won't work;

```
(Int16)2147483683;
```

because `Int16` can hold `32787` as maximum value. You can use [`unchecked (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a569z7k8.aspx) keyword such this cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you force an unchecked operation, a cast should work:

```
int r = 0xF000001;
short trimmed = unchecked((short) r);
```

This will truncate the value of `r` to fit in a short.

If the value of `r` should always fit in a `short`, you can just do a normal cast and let an exception be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, make sure you actually want to have the value signed. `uint` and `ushort` are there for a reason. Then:

```
ushort ret = (ushort)(val & ((1 << 16) - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 16 bit value and you happen to know something specific like that the number will never be less than zero, you could use a UINT16 value. That conversion looks like:

```
 int x = 0;
 UInt16 value = (UInt16)x;
```

This has the full (positive) range of an integer.